# Unmarshalling with JAXB leads to : javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException (invalid byte sequence)

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

Here's my problem : I've written a program that unmarshals an XML file given as input and it turns out that my program works just fine on my development environment **BUT** this same program will yield the following exception on my client's environment :

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.]

The XML file given as input to my program is using UTF-8 as encoding type. The Unmarshaller object is using the default encoding type, that is UTF-8, since I did not set any property value to it. Besides, I did not set a schema to the unmarshaller, so, I am not even requesting an XML validation.

Does anyone have any idea or has anyone already ran into the same problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have already get this error. I have change my configuration to use ISO-8859-1 encoding :
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");

i can put UTF-8 strings in the xml flow, it's correctly marshall/unmarshall even if the encoding is not define like ISO-8859-1